# Why is it not recommended to change strings in a loop? What is recommended to use?

Tags: java, string

a question from the Java interview preparation that I didn't find an answer to

Why is it not recommended to change strings in a loop? What is recommended to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable objects and therefore possibly the compiler has to create at least one new object to hold the result when appending to strings. Constructing a string in a loop requires creating a new string in every iteration and therefore consuming more time and memory. This will affect the performance of the algorithm badly.

[This](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/JAVA/String+concatenation+in+loop) provides a solution to update strings using StringBuffer or StringBuilder.

```
r = new Random(120);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    sb.append(r.nextInt(2));
}
s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: And for  s smidgen more efficiency, you could preallocate the buffer: `new StringBuilder(100)` -- the size given should be more than you expect to need, but not absurdly so. Here it's easy to figure out.